# Has anyone run Sphinx from Ant?

Tags: ant, python-sphinx

I'm using [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org) for some software documentation because it seems to work really well... but my project is a Java project and I would like to run Sphinx from an Ant script.

Has anyone written a custom Ant task to call Sphinx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No on the sphinx specific question.

However (you probably already know this): You can run practically any program, especially any command line application, using ant's `exec` task.

Comment: If you wanted, you could wrap the `exec` task in a `macrodef` and have a more descriptive `sphinx` task in the build file.

Comment: I defined an exec task and it worked well. Just goes to show you should try the mundane approaches first before the clever ones.